# On t-core partitions

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

How exactly can one define what is known as a t-core partition? I know (vaguely) that it involves the definition  of what is known as "Hook numbers".

Anyone cares to provide a link or explain it?

Answer (score 1):

A t-core partition is a partition such that none of the hook lengths are divisible by $t$.

You can find a definition of hook length on the [hook length formula page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) and illustrated in [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hook-length_tableau_December_8_2013_3.jpg).